# How to fix visual studio 2013 missing project templates

Tags: visual-studio

Has anyone got a solution on how to restore the missing project templates in Visual Studio 2013. I have tried to repair & uninstall/reinstall Visual Studio but still face the same issue.

[image]

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms247116%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to remove Visual Studio completely, restart my laptop, delete all visual studio directories in c:/program files & then clean up the registry using ccleaner.

I then reinstalled visual studio & was able to see the templates again :)